# Axios Authentication credentials were not provided error when posting to api in production env

Tags: next.js, django-rest-framework, axios, react-hook-form

I have a next.js app on vercel that can submit a form to Django api. The submits successfully in the dev environment, sending all files successfully but in production, I keep getting 403 Forbidden error from the frontend with details:
`Authentication credentials were not provided` even though I added `withCredentials: false` flag. My Django view does not require any credentials, authorization, or authentication to accept the form.

Below is the submit function from the next app:

```
 const submitForm = async (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      let response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: registrationURL,
        data: data,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        withCredentials: false,
      });
      console.log(data);
      if (response.data.status === "success") reset();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setServerErrors(true);
    }
  };
```

Below is my views.py file:

```
class RegistrationFormView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FormSerializer
    queryset = CourseRegistrationForm.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)


    def post(self, request, format=None):
        
        serializer = FormSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In settings.py I have this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

I sometimes receive this error in my nginx server but don't know if it's really related to the proble:
`684 open() "/home/ubuntu/oicnm-backend/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-tweaks.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)`